Сreating multilevel json with the jq utility in a bash script
I get the contents of a text file into an array and then sequentially get the elements of the array and try to add the elements to the json:
#!/bin/bash

JSON=$(jq -n '')
readarray -t array < ./station.sample
count=0

for e in "${array[@]}"
do
    if echo "$e" | grep -Eq '^[0-9]{10}' >/dev/null
      then
        timestamp=$e
        datetime=`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "@$e"`
        JSON=$(echo $JSON | jq --arg timestamp "${timestamp}" '. += $ARGS.named')
        JSON=$(echo $JSON | jq --arg datetime "${datetime}" '. += $ARGS.named')
    fi

    if echo "$e" | grep '^Station ' >/dev/null
      then
        NODE=$(jq -n '')
        mac=`echo "$e" | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        interface=`echo "$e" | awk '{ print $4 }' | rev | cut -c2- | rev`

        JSON=$(echo $JSON | jq --argjson nodes "[]" '. += $ARGS.named')
        JSON=$(echo $JSON | jq --arg mac "${mac}" --arg count "${count}" '.nodes[0] += {"mac": $mac}')
    JSON=$(echo $JSON | jq --arg interface "${interface}" '.nodes[0] += {"interface": $interface}')

        count=$((count+1))
    fi
done

As a result, I get a json like this:
{
  "timestamp": "1721396365",
  "datetime": "2024-07-19 16:39:25",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "mac": "14:88:00:00:00:06"
    }
  ]
}

But I need to add multiple objects to the list, so I set a count variable and want to use it to specify the index of the list:
JSON=$(echo $JSON | jq --arg mac "${mac}" --arg count "${count}" '.nodes[$count] += {"mac": $mac}')

But in this variant adding list items doesn't work.
How can I dynamically specify the index of the list?
I've tried all the options that came to mind, but I haven't found a solution yet:
 NODE=$(echo $NODE | jq --arg mac "$mac" '. += $ARGS.named')
 NODE=$(echo $NODE | jq --arg interface "${interface}" '. += $ARGS.named')
 JSON=$(echo $JSON | jq --argjson node "${NODE}" '.nodes[.nodes | length] = $ARGS.named')

It is necessary to use a variable to specify the index of the list.

Can you edit your question to add an extract of the source text file and a sample of the desired JSON output?

Check your script with shellcheck. echo "$JSON". Did you consider just using something with JSON support? Like python? I need to add multiple objects to the list, What is the content of the input file then? If there is a next timestamp should it start a new object or overwrite or we do not care? Also, most probably, jq is also a language by itself that could potentially handle reading from file and parsing it.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

@EdMorton Lets give him a chance to improve his post as a new user. Not sure his problems would be solved with Shellcheck alone and he documented his attempts at solving the problem by himself. Now I am not sur he has enough reputation yet to edit his own question but he could at least reply with comments.

@LéaGris we've asked the stackoverflow folks to add a template for questions that would run shellcheck, they've refused to do so, and so it's up to the community to require all questions be shellcheck-clean if we don't want to waste time finding/explaining issues a tool could handle and wondering if they are causing the problem. Asking people to run shellcheck doesnt work but closing the question until they run shellcheck and then reopening it would work. Otherwise we just continue being flooded with questions where we have to waste time explaining issues that shellcheck could catch/explain.

So, going forward I'm just going to vote to close any questions that aren't shellcheck clean so I can focus on the ones that are and hopefully others will do the same so we all waste less time repeatedly finding/explaining the basic issues that shellcheck can handle, and only repeatedly finding/explaining the basic issues that shellcheck can't handle along with more complex issues and actually helping people with their real problems. The [tag:bash] tag already tells posters to run shellcheck before posting a question so that doesn't seen unreasonable to me. Anyone can edit their question btw.

@LéaGris, I don't believe editing a question one asked oneself has any reputation requirement -- my understanding is that those requirements are only for editing questions asked by others.

Running a bunch of tiny jq calls instead of fewer, larger ones that do more work in each invocation really doesn't make any sense -- your script is going to spend a ridiculous amount of time just spinning up new copies of jq for no good reason whatsoever. Write your jq to accept, say, a list of lines, each of which takes a tab-separated series of columns with the items you want to add, and then you can just run jq only once and have it consume that whole stream in one go.


.nodes[$count] += {"mac": $mac}
But in this variant adding list items doesn't work.

That's because when you use += for arrays, the RHS must be an array, like so:
 .nodes[$count] += [{"mac": $mac}]


By the way, I suspect you could greatly simplify things by using jq to do all (or at least nearly all) the required manipulations, thus avoiding the bash/awk/grep messiness.

It was interesting to deep dive into jq scripting, and here it is.
There is no clue as to what the input is and what the desired output is, so here are my assumptions:

Input data is lines starting with Unix timestamps or starting with Station  (nodes), and other ignored lines. 
Simple input generator:
for _i in {0..10}; do
  case $_i in
  1 | 7 | 8)
    echo "$(date +%s -d "now - $((10 - $_i)) days") rest..";;
  4)
    echo "other log line";;
  *)
    printf "Station 14:88:00:00:00:%02X some   iface%d.12x rest...\n" "$_i" "$_i";;
  esac;
done >./station.sample


Output is a grouping of stations/nodes ("mac" and "iface") by unix timestamps. 
The result for test input above:
[
  {
    "nodes": [
      {"mac": "14:88:00:00:00:00", "interface": "iface0.12"}
    ]
  }, {
    "timestamp": 1721465934, "datetime": "2024-07-20 08:58:54",
    "nodes": [
      {"mac": "14:88:00:00:00:02", "interface": "iface2.12"},
      {"mac": "14:88:00:00:00:03", "interface": "iface3.12"},
      {"mac": "14:88:00:00:00:05", "interface": "iface5.12"},
      {"mac": "14:88:00:00:00:06", "interface": "iface6.12"}
    ]
  }, {
    "timestamp": 1721984334, "datetime": "2024-07-26 08:58:54",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "timestamp": 1722070734, "datetime": "2024-07-27 08:58:54",
    "nodes": [
      {"mac": "14:88:00:00:00:09", "interface": "iface9.12"},
      {"mac": "14:88:00:00:00:0A", "interface": "iface10.12"}
    ]
  }
]



Here is jq filter, save this into filter.jq:
[
  inputs |                     # read input file line by line without parsing, this requere -Rn flags
  if test("^\\d{10}") then     # parse line with unix timestamps
    .[0:10] | tonumber | {
      timestamp: .,
      # NOTE: there is a bug in 'strflocaltime()' with '%z' formatter, use '%Z' instead, see https://github.com/jqlang/jq/issues/2429
      datetime: strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
    }
  elif test("^Station ") then  # parse line with "station"
    [splits("\\s+")] | {
      mac: .[1],
      interface: .[3][:-1],    # trim last character
    }
  else                         # other lines, skip them
    empty
  end
] + [{timestamp: null}] |      # append empty object for complete last group in the following 'foreach'
[
  foreach .[] as $_o (         # groupping timestamps and stations/nodes
    [[], []];
    if $_o | has("timestamp") then [[$_o], .[0]] else [(.[0] + [$_o]), []] end;
    if ($_o | has("timestamp")) and (.[1] | length) > 0 then
      if .[1][0] | has("timestamp") then
        .[1][0] + {nodes: .[1][1:]}
      else
        {nodes: .[1]}          # case without Unix timestamp (file beginning)
      end
    else
      empty
    end
  )
]

This filter should be run with the -Rn flags, e.g.:
jq -Rn -f ./filter.jq <./station.sample


OP's output is a single object, not an array. Also it's local time, not GM time.

@Philippe, yes, in my answer I used an array of objects and that is my assumption for the OP's desired output. Mainly because there is no additional information related to requested comments.
Fixed printing "datetime" in local time.
